# Add Polygon Feature in QGIS: polygon lines follow cursor when digitizing

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

I am drawing polygons in QGIS by moving the cursor and clicking to add polygon corners.  So, four clicks, four corners to a polygon.  All of a sudden, the polygon lines get drawn as I move the cursor, not when I click to create a corner.  I must have accidentally changed something without knowing it.  How do I get back to drawing polygons by clicking on the corners?

Answer (score 1):

You probably clicked `R` key and with this activated [Streaming Digitizing mode](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-streaming-digitizing-mode), introduced in QGIS 3.20. Click again `R` key to deactivate.

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. The policy of this site is to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235